# Set display value to empty when open - HeadlessUI Combobox

Tags: reactjs, combobox, headless-ui

I'm new to React. I got a question regarding [Combobox of HeadlessUI](https://headlessui.com/react/combobox).

How do we set the value to empty when combobox is open? I'm trying to follow this autocomplete pattern below. When the options are opened, the input value is set to empty, so user can type straight away.

[image]

This is from existing example of Combobox, see that the input value is not empty when options are opened

[image]

What I have tried so far is to checking the `open` state of combobox inside `displayValue`, but it didn't work. The `open` is definitely not matched with the current `open` state. I believe because the function store the previous value of `open`.

```
<Combobox.Input                
  displayValue={(person) => {
    console.log("open", open);

    if (open) {
      return "";
    }

    return person.name;
  }}
  onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)}
/>
```

Here is my [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tailwind-headless-ui-i5yij7?file=/src/App.js).

I noticed we have two render props for `Combobox.Input` which are `open` and `disabled`. How to use that prop?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `key` props to your `Combobox.Input`, it should work

```
<Combobox.Input
  key={open}               
  displayValue={(person) => {
    if (open) {
      return "";
    }

    return person.name;
  }}
  onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you @iamhuynq. It works but I got a typing error https://share.cleanshot.com/WIYWAr. Anyway, what is the explanation about using `key` approach?

Comment: @deerawan I think Combobox.Input use memo, displayValue function not receive new value of open because its not re-render when open changed. So I pass key props to force re-render input and it will receive new value of open state